# Undefined variable when returning view as HTML via AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to prepend the view when adding a new category. I'm always getting the error:

> Undefined variable: category (View: ..new.blade.php) ... Line 1

Here's what I have so far:

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->save();

        $returnHTML = view('categories.new', compact($category))->render();
        return response()->json(array(
            'success' => true, 
            'html' => $returnHTML,
            'icon' => 'success',
            'title' => 'Added',
            'msg' => 'Category successfully added.'
        ));
    }
```

**script.blade.php**

```
$('#category-submit').click( function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        let _url = '/categories';
        let _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                name: name,
                _token: _token
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('tbody').prepend(data.html);

                $('#name').val('');

                $('#category-modal').modal('hide');

                Swal.fire({
                    title: data.title,
                    text: data.msg,
                    icon: data.icon,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

**new.blade.php**

```
<tr id="category-{{ $category->id }}">
    <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-inverse-primary btn-icon-text">
            <i class="ti-pencil btn-icon-prepend"></i> Edit
        </button>
        <button data-id="{{ $category->id }}" class="category-delete btn btn-inverse-danger btn-icon-text">
            <i class="ti-trash btn-icon-prepend"></i> Delete
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. It seems `$category` from controller won't be passed to `new.blade.php`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try To Use  `$returnHTML = view('categories.new', compact('category'))->render();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here in php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php), you should pass the name of the variable as a string in `compact()` method.

```
$returnHTML = view('categories.new', compact('category'))->render();
```

Or you can pass the variable to blade file using array.

```
$returnHTML = view('categories.new', ['category' => $category])->render();
```